# row.components.setDisabled(true) not working

Tags: discord.js

For some reason, row.components[4].setDisabled(true) does not work. After clicking on the button, it does not disable despite the attributes saying that it has.

```
if (id == "right") {
    shopcounter += 1
    if ((shopcounter+1) * 3 > itemarray.length) {
        row.components[4].setDisabled(true)
        console.log(row.components[4])
        return ButtonInteraction.first().reply("No more pages!")
    }
    shopCommand(receivedMessage,user)
    return ButtonInteraction.first().reply("Next page!")
}
```

It outputs

```
MessageButton {
  type: 'BUTTON',
  label: null,
  customId: 'right',
  style: 'PRIMARY',
  emoji: { id: null, name: '➡️', animated: false },
  url: null,
  disabled: true
}
```

[image: After clicking the right button]

Comment: You are setting the `disabled` property, but never edit the message

Comment: Wait so how do i edit the message?

Comment: `Message.edit`. You will need to update the new messages buttons before editing

Comment: Um im not too sure how to edit my embed and I already tried looking for tutorials but its too fast for me. How does Message.edit work?

Comment: I finally managed to find out how to edit the message into an embed by doing message.edit({embeds: [shopEmbed], components: [row] })